# Arduino - how to change TFmini's measure unit to mm

Tags: arduino, lidar

I'm making a 3D scanner using TFMini-S Lidar alone with Arduino Uno.  The Lidar default to cm, but I want to use mm instead.  However everywhere I look, I can't find any clear way to do it.  After reading the documentation, I discovered the TFMini is factory programed to use cm.  But it also mentions that there are commands that can change the unit to mm.

> The value of distance output Dist may vary with the output unit, which is cm by default. If the
> unit of distance is changed to the unit-mm via an instruction, and the PC software will be unable
> to identify it, and so the unit of “④TIME LINE CHART” will still be cm. For example, the actual
> TFmini measurement is 1m, the distance value of TFmini is 1000 in mm, the value read by the
> PC software also is 1000, but the unit will not change and still display cm.

And this is all I can find about how to do that from some other website:

> TFmin LiDAR sensor has updated with the output unit mm to cm now. There is the configuration commands that can set the output unit by your need:
> “Changes to the mm: send 42 57 02 00 00 0 01, 02 to enter configuration mode, then send 42 57 02 00 00 00 00 1A;
> Change to cm: send 42 57 02 00 00 0 01, 02 to enter configuration mode, then send 42 57 02 00 00 00 01 1A.”

I'm a beginner to Arduino and I'm not sure how to send those configuration commands.  If there are similar resources, please let me know.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: learn how to use serial communication. this is covered by any Arduino tutorial.

Comment: I suppose the [Arduino TFMini Library code on github](https://github.com/opensensinglab/tfmini/blob/master/src/TFMini.cpp) could be an entry point.  The library doesn't set cm/mm, but does send parameter configuration messages.  So you can see how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found from TFMini-Plus library, but it works with TFMini-S/TFMini as well.

The "STANDARD_FORMAT_MM" command will set the measure unit to mm, but make sure to save using "SAVE_SETTINGS" command.  Refer to the Github example code for your own project.

Big thanks to the creator of that Github repo.

//source code********************************************************

```
#include <TFMPlus.h>
#include "printf.h"  
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>  
TFMPlus tfmP;
SoftwareSerial mySerial( ?,?);   
                                    
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(????); 
    if( tfmP.sendCommand( STANDARD_FORMAT_MM, 0))
    {
      printf("mm set");
      if( tfmP.sendCommand( SAVE_SETTINGS, 0))
      {
          printf("setting saved");
      }
      else tfmP.printReply();
    }
    else tfmP.printReply();
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I wasn't able to implement it. Could you please share the code for me to understand it well?

Comment: updated with src snipped,, hope it helps :)